# jQuery: поведение программы после добавления css-класса

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Это скрипт должен циклически показывать и скрывать меню при нажатии кнопки:

```
$(".menu-btn:first").click(switchMenu);

function switchMenu(){

  var menu = $(".menu:first");
  if (!menu.hasClass('menu-show')){        
   menu.addClass('menu-show');
  }
  else {
   menu.removeClass('menu-show');
 }  
};
```

Я попадаю в `if` (т. е. не в `else`) при каждом нажатии кнопки, а не через раз. С помощью `alert` я убедился, что после добавления класса `menu-show` обновления переменной `menu` не происходит. Почему так?

- Этот скрипт находится сразу после HTML-кода (допустим, мне так удобно в этой задаче).
- Вне функции `addClass` и `removeClass` работают, а это значит, что в строках с этими методами ошибки нет.
- Почитал несколько источников, но так чётко и не понял, какая разница между `switchMenu()` и `swhitchMenu`. Элкспериментально установил, что в данном скрипте при замене `switchMenu` на `switchMenu()` функция вызвается без всякого нажатия кнопки, меню показывается, а после нажания кнопки программа попадает в `else`. Совершенно не понимаю, что происходит.
- Но самое интересное: если после функции `switchMenu()` добавить `menu.removeClass('menu-show');` то отладчик `GoogleChrome`, естественно, выдаст ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: menu is not defined`, но кнопка при этом заработает корректно!

Объясните пожалуйста поведение этого скрипта.

---

**Обновление** А вот и причина: функция, следующая за `switchMenu()`. Данная функция (`switchMenu`) убирает меню только при нажатии на кнопку, а указанная ниже функция - при клике вне меню в любое место.

```
$(function($){
  $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    var menu =  $(".menu"); 
    if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
    $(".menu").removeClass('menu-show'); 
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Довольно странное поведение.

3. Тут все логично, нужно передавать саму функцию, которая будет вызываться при наступлении события, а не её вызов - тут все правильно;
4. Тут тоже все верно, т.к. `menu` объявлена внутри функции и за пределами функции при обращении к переменной будет ошибка, что она не объявлена.

Ваш пример отлично работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".menu-btn:first").click(switchMenu);

  function switchMenu() {

    var menu = $(".menu:first");
    if (!menu.hasClass('menu-show')) {
      menu.addClass('menu-show');
    } else {
      menu.removeClass('menu-show');
    }
  };

});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu">menu</nav>
<button class="menu-btn">toggle menu</button>
```

Comment: вероятно, причина в том, что Ваш код находится внутри '$(document).ready(function() {', а у меня нет. Как устранить ошибку - я понял, но с поведением функции пока теория не ясна.

Comment: Да и без обертки $(document).ready(function() {}) данный код должен нормально отрабатывать. Возможно ошибка связана с html кодом

Comment: Нашел причину.  Дело в том, что эта функция конфликтует с ещё одной, которую добавил в вопрос. ` function switchMenu() ` убирает меню только при нажатии на кнопку,  но я добавил ещё функцию, которая делает тоже самое при клике вне поля меню.