# JavaScript: конфликт функций скрытия DOM разными способами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Этот вопрос является продолжением темы [jQuery: поведение программы после добавления css-класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586645/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-css-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). В том вопросе рассматривалось типичное hamburger-меню. Оказалось, что в опубликованном коде ошибок не было, а просто функция конфликтует с ещё одной, которая не включена в код. Разрешение этого конфликта и является предметом обсуждения текущего вопроса.

Работающая функция, выдвигающая меню по нажатию кнопки:

```
$(".menu-btn:first").click(switchMenu);
function switchMenu() {
var menu = $(".menu:first");

 if (!menu.hasClass('menu-show')) {
  menu.addClass('menu-show');
 } else {
    menu.removeClass('menu-show');
 }
};
```

Теперь мы хотим, чтобо меню можно было убрать ещё и при клике в любое место вне поля этого меню. Функция для этого есть:

```
$(function($){
    $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
        if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
            menu.removeClass('menu-show'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Однако, это две функции конфликтуют:

- Если обе функции будут идти друг за другом в указанном порядке, то переменная `menu` не будет доступна во второй функции, потому меню будет убираться при нажатии на кнопку, но не при клике вне поля меню.
- Если переменную `menu` вынести за пределы функции, то ситуация изменится на прямо противоположную: меню не будет закрываться кнопкой, но при клике вне поля - исчезнет.

Как можно объединить функционал двух функций в минимум строк?

---

Исходник [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/t3z7xy57/). Сейчас меню закрывается только при клике вне меню. Если убрать весь JS-код, кроме первых трёх строк, то будет закрываться только кнопкой.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` https://jsfiddle.net/t3z7xy57/1/

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение. Оформите, пожалуйста, Ваше решение как ответ, чтобы я мог по крайней мере поставить Вам галочку и плюс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема кода, приведенного в Вашем вопросе, в том, что при нажатии на кнопку выстреливают оба события, причем `mouseup` вызывается первым.

```
$(".opt-menu-btn:first").click(function(event) {
  $(".opt-menu-mob:first").toggleClass('opt-menu-mob-show');
  console.log('btn click');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e){ 
  var menu =  $(".opt-menu-mob:first"); 
  if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
    menu.removeClass('opt-menu-mob-show'); 
    console.log('doc click');
  }
});
```

Или один обработчик:

```
$(document).click(function (e){ 
  var menu =  $(".opt-menu-mob:first"); 
  if ($(".opt-menu-btn:first")[0] == e.target) {
    $(".opt-menu-mob:first").toggleClass('opt-menu-mob-show');
  } else if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
    menu.removeClass('opt-menu-mob-show'); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение. Выбрал Вас победителем за более короткий код.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно это вам поможет https://jsfiddle.net/vv3odufc/1/

В вашем случае нужно отключать bubbling событий из нужных элементов.
С помощью event.StopPropagation();

```
// изолируемся от глобальной видимости
(function ($) {
// код начнет работать когда html будет готов
   $(function () {
      var menu = $(".menu"),
          menu_btn = $(".menu-btn");

        // слушаем событие клик на элементе
        menu_btn.on("click", function (event) {

           if (!menu.hasClass('menu-show')) {
             menu.addClass('menu-show');
           } else {
             menu.removeClass('menu-show');
           }

           // отключаем bubbling события
           event.stopPropagation();
       });

    // можно кликать на меню и оно не закроется
    menu.on("click", function (event) {
         // отключаем bubbling события
         event.stopPropagation();
    });

    // при клике в любое место кроме меню и кнопки открывания меню
    // меню закроется
    $(document).on("click", function () {
      menu.removeClass('menu-show');
    });

  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Я доработал ваш код https://jsfiddle.net/t3z7xy57/2/

Comment: Благодарю Вас за Ваше время. К сожалению, по правилам форума, я могу дать приз только одному ответившему. Пожалуйста, продолжайте отвечать на вопросы и Вы быстро наберёте репутацию на форуме.

Answer (score 1):

Во второй функции нужно объявить переменную `menu`

```js
$(".menu-btn:first").click(function() {
  $(".menu:first").toggleClass('menu-show');
});

$(function($) {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var menu = $(".menu:first");
    if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      menu.removeClass('menu-show');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за код. К сожалению, вероятно у Вас ошибка. `this` - это же кнопка, верно? Тогда судя по коду, мы класс `menu-show` присваиваем кнопке, а не меню.

Comment: Исправил на `$('.menu:first').toggleClass('menu-show');`; проблема осталась.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Прошу прощения, не заметил, что у Вас разные классы. Да, Ваше исправление правильно. Проблема остаться не могла, т.к. я убрал все обращения к глобальным переменным. Либо у Вас какой-то свой код, либо проблема уже другая

Comment: Ну не знаю... [Вот код](https://jsfiddle.net/t3z7xy57/), насколько возможно упрощённый от моего кода, но работающией так, как я описал выше. Сейчас меню можно убрать только кликнув вне его, а уберёте первые три строки JS-кода - меню будет переключаться только кнопкой.