# JavaScript: избежать срабатывания двух событий при клике вне указананного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В [одном из своих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586676/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-dom-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) я спрашивал, как можно открывать и закрывать hamburger-меню с помощью кнопки, а также кликом вне открытого меню, при этом кнопка находилась поверх меню. К сожалению, не сумел применить эти знания к случаю, когда кнопка находится не поверх меню, а, например, рядом с ним.

```
$('#menu-button').click(function(){
       $("#menu-field").show('slow');
       event.stopPropagation();
    });
};

$(document).click(function() {
    if( this.id !== 'menu-field"') {
      $("#menu-field").hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Такой код не закрывает меню нажатием кнопки.

Как и в предыдущем вопросе, коротко задачу можно описать так: сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходило только одно событие.

Другая проблема в данной задачи в том, что её едва ли можно решить без использования глобальных объектов (как `document`). Это выражается в том, что если мы объявим переменную-переключатель (типа `menuShown = false`) или функцию-рычаг (типа `showMenu()`), они не будут видны во втором блоке кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой задачи можно использовать `event.target` и *Jquery* функцию `closest`

```js
$('#menu-button').click(function(){
  $("#menu-field").show('slow');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if($(event.target).closest('#menu-field').length == 0){
    $("#menu-field").hide('slow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menu-button">Кнопка</button>

<p id="menu-field" style="display:none;">Текст. <span>А это внутренний элемент</span></p>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение. К сожалению, нажатие кнопки с целью скрыть текст не приводит к его изчезновению.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu все правильно, у вас же show написано.

Comment: Прошу прощения, Вы правы. Значит надо на toggle заменить. Ещё раз благодарю Вас за ответ.